# Aligning content with even spacing with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

This is difficult to explain so please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vhfhzgfz/

Say I have a row of 4 columns using Bootstrap. I want the content within these cols to be equal distances apart. The content has a fixed width in `px`.

The content in the first column needs to be aligned to the left (edge of the page) and the content in the last col aligned to the right (the other edge of the page). This is fine.

But how do I align the content in the middle two columns to ensure the space between the content is equal.

Here's the code form the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhfhzgfz/):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 left">
            <div class="wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 center">
            <div class="wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 center">
            <div class="wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 right">
            <div class="wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.col-xs-3{
    background:lightblue;
    outline:solid 1px black;
}
.wrapper{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:pink;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.left{
    text-align:left;
}

.right{
    text-align:right;
}

.center{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Is Bootstap an requirement? `flexbox` makes this pretty easy - http://jsfiddle.net/vhfhzgfz/3/

Comment: Yea @Paulie_D, sadly bootstrap is a requirement. Good solution though.